getting decimal places in confidence intervals for survey analysis
I am using the below R code but cannot figure our how to get the confidence intervals with two decimal places:
library(gtsummary)
survey::svydesign(id = ~PSU, weights = ~WT_analysis,  strata = ~Stratum, data = nyts23_drop_na)|>
tbl_svysummary(digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)), by = ADDI_cat1, percent = "column", 
             include = c(SCHOOLTYPE,race_cat,SEX,sex_ori)) |>
add_stat_label() |>
add_ci(pattern = "{stat} (95% CI {ci})") |>
add_p()

I tried the above code but could not get the confidence intervals with two decimal places. I was able to get the two decimal places for the statistic but not the same (i.e., two decimal places) for the confidence intervals around these statistics.

does the style_fun parameter allow you to make the change you're looking for?  thanks!
library(srvyr)
library(gtsummary)
data(api, package = "survey")
apistrat %>% 
    as_survey_design(strata = stype, weights = pw) %>%
    tbl_svysummary(digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)), by = awards, percent = "column", 
                 include = c(both,stype)) |>
    add_stat_label() |>
    add_ci(
        pattern = "{stat} (95% CI {ci})",
        style_fun = 
            list(
                all_continuous() ~ label_style_sigfig(), 
                all_categorical() ~ label_style_sigfig(scale = 100,digits=4)
            )
    ) |>
    add_p()


This worked, I was able to add the PSU as well by tweaking the code a little: as_survey_design(ids=PSU, strata = Stratum, weights = WT_analysis), Thank you so much!
